# Putchar character is appearing at the front of my printf function

Tags: c, printf, putchar

Using this code

```
void echo_char_code() {
    int x;
    printf ("Please enter a character:\n");
    x = getchar();
    printf("The character code of '%c' is %d", putchar(x), putchar(x));
    printf(". \n");
}

int main() {
    echo_char_code();
    return 0;
}
```

but for some reason my output is

`AAThe character code of 'A' is 65.`

and I'm wondering why the "AA" is appearing at the start and not just as the 'A' & 65 that I want it too.

Comment: _Why_ do you call putchar?

Comment: It should be `printf("The character code of '%c' is %d", x, x);` Why does it otherwise work? Because `int putchar(int c);` *Returns the character written.*

Comment: You call `putchar` twice, and two mysterious characters appear on the output ... i'm stumped

Comment: @M.M Would you like to rephrase your comment, so as to make the helpful part, the polite part, the original part and the insightful part more obvious? Those parts are currently hard to see. The part where you make fun of the OP in a way that cannot be any more valuable than other comments and answers might be in the way and hiding them.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't pass putchar(x) as argument, instead use the variable x.

```
void echo_char_code() {
    int x;
    printf ("Please enter a character:\n");
    x = getchar ();
    printf("The character code of '%c' is %d", x, x)); // changing putchar(x) to x solves the problem.
    printf (". \n");
}

int main() {
    echo_char_code();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
printf("The character code of '%c' is %d",putchar(x),putchar(x));
```

you are calling `putchar()` twice, which outputs x twice.
You are also using the return values of those two calls to do a formatted output.
The return value of `putchar()` happens to be (in case of success) the written char, which makes it somewhat transparent.
The order of this is probably not predictable, but it does explain your observed result.

Compare https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/putchar
it states

> Return value
>   On success, returns the written character.